# typeorm update entity after insert in entity subscriber

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

How can I update an entity in afterInsert? If i call `manager.save()` it throws

> QueryRunnerAlreadyReleasedError: Query runner already released. Cannot run queries anymore.

```
async afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<any>) {
    console.log(`AFTER ENTITY INSERTED: `, event.entity.id);
    this.doStuff().then(entity => {
        event.manager.save(entity);
    });
}
```

Comment: What kind of `post insert` `update` are you looking to do? Is there a reason you can't do it before the `insert`?

Comment: yeah i need the auto generated id for that...

Comment: Can you give a little more insight on why you need the autogenerated id? What are you doing to the record you just saved? There's really not much to help with at the moment with what you've given.

Comment: well, i make a http req to  another service and for that i need the id...

Comment: Okay, but what do you do with that request that you need to resave to the database? There really isn't enough here to help you. Right now it seems like you'll need to run your insert, then your external call, then your update, all in a synchronous manner.